# Is it possible control TI BLE (bluetooth low energy) press key by iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I already search the answer to do this several days, and I try many ways but no use.

I have a project to control the key/switch on/off in TI cc2540, but I couldn't find the way to do that.

I make a similar function as buzzer like this:
in TIBLEKeyfob.m

```
-(void) ControlKeyValue:(int)newValue p:(CBPeripheral *)p{
NSData *v = [[NSDataalloc] initWithBytes:&newValue length:1];
[self writeValue:TI_KEYFOB_KEYS_SERVICE_UUID 
characteristicUUID:TI_KEYFOB_KEYS_CHAR_CFG_UUID p:p data:v];}
```

and add new #define

```
#define TI_KEYFOB_KEYS_SERVICE_UUID                         0xFFE0
#define TI_KEYFOB_KEYS_NOTIFICATION_UUID                    0xFFE1
#define TI_KEYFOB_KEYS_CHAR_CFG_UUID                        0x2902
#define TI_KEYFOB_KEYS_NOTIFICATION_READ_LEN                     1
```

I add this in the IBAction and want to try to make command to control key/switch

```
- (IBAction)keySwitchButton:(id)sender {
[tControlKeyValue:2 p:[tactivePeripheral]];}
```

But I got follow log error:

```
Could not find characteristic with UUID <2902>
on service with UUID <ffe0> on peripheral with UUID 
F97E5249-B626-FA74-40FF-9B08FAB44966
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem~?

my question is

1. Is it possible to use iphone to control the key/switch of cc2540 on/off?
2. If could, could I just control one of them?( there are two buttons, I only need right one)
3. If 1. and 2. could do, how shold I modify my code?

Or I almost got wrong orientation?
Thanks >"<~!!

Comment: First test: Download LightBlue app from AppStore, test if you can do what you want. If yes, let's check what's wrong.
I guess that you don't record the characteristic discovered, but I want you to do the test with LightBlue before.

Comment: Wao~!! Thanks for your help Larme!!:D:D
I installed the LightBlue app, and I got the inform about Key service, but...seems that there is no characteristic for control the key value( only one notify characteristic in 0xFFE0 service)...

Comment: Does that mean I can't make some command to CC2540? >"<?